# Parameters as storage in recursion - Return an array using recursion of all values from startNum to endNum

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

In learning about recursion, I've come across this problem and I've solved it, but not in the way I would like.  In my solution, I'm storing values within an array declared in global scope.

Here's my code:

```js
//I don't want array in global scope, but within the function
let array = [];

const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum) => {

  if (startNum === endNum) {
    array.splice(0, 0, startNum);
    return array;
  }

  {
    array.splice(0, 0, endNum);
    // console.log(array)
    const newEndNum = endNum - 1;
    endNum = newEndNum;
    return rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum);

  }

}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 10))
```

I've tried including it as an argument `const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum, array = [])` but that leads to the recreation of an array every time the function is called, so when I call the function recursively, so the returned value is an array of a single value `[6]`.  The same (undesired) behavior is observed when I declare a mutable variable within the function scope

```
const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum) => {

  let array = [];

  if(startNum === endNum) {...
```

As far as I understand, the splice method should not be an issue here, since it isn't deleting any elements.

In general, I'm having trouble understanding how to formulate the easiest base case whenever I try to solve problems recursively.  So I have a feeling that - even though I think the base logic is screwing me.

Points to anyone who can offer hints on how to think of this more clearly, rather than simply offering the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check if the `startNum` and `endNum` are equal. If they are return `[startNum]`. If not, return `[startNum]` and concat to it the result of calling `rangeOfNumbers` with `startNum` incremented by 1:

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum) =>
  startNum === endNum ?
    [startNum]
    :
    [startNum].concat(rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum));

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 10))
```

Another non functional approach (the `arr` is mutated) is to create a function that holds the array, and run the recursion inside it:

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum) => {
  const arr = [];
  
  const fn = (startNum, endNum) => {
    arr.push(startNum);
  
    if(startNum !== endNum) fn(startNum + 1, endNum);
  };
  
  fn(startNum, endNum);
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 10))
```

This is a bi-directional approach based on @ThankYou's solution. The main difference is that it uses `(b - a) / Math.abs(b - a)` to calculate the step - 1 / -1.

```js
const range = (a, b, r = []) =>
  a === b
    ? [...r, a]
    : range(a + (b - a) / Math.abs(b - a), b, [...r, a])

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(0,7)))   // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(3,9)))   // [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(9,3)))   // [9,8,7,6,5,4,3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-3,-7))) // [-3,-4,-5,-6,-7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-7,-3))) // [-7,-6,-5,-4,-3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(2,-2)))  // [2,1,0,-1,-2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-2,2)))  // [-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question asks how you can use parameters *"as storage"* and this example hopes to show such a technique -

1. if `a` is greater than `b`, the base case has been reached. return the result, `r`
2. (inductive) `a` is less than or equal to `b`. Append `a` to the result and recur on the sub-problem `(a+1, b)`

```js
const range = (a, b, r = []) =>
  a > b
    ? r                           // # 1
    : range(a + 1, b, [...r, a])  // # 2
    
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(0,7))) // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(3,9))) // [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(9,3))) // []
```

If you prefer the more verbose variable names -

```js
const range = (startNum, endNum, result = []) =>
  startNum > endNum
    ? result 
    : range(startNum + 1, endNum, [...result, startNum])
```

And here's a variant of `range` that allows you to build ranges in either direction -

1. if `a` is greater than `b`, compute the reversed range, `(b,a)` and `.reverse` the result
2. (inductive) `a` is less than or equal to `b`. If `a` is less than `b`, append `a` to the result and recur on the sub-problem `(a+1, b)`
3. (inductive) `a` is equal to `b`. The base case has been met, append `a` to the result and return

```js
const range = (a, b, r = []) =>
  a > b
    ? range(b, a).reverse()        // #1
: a < b
    ? range(a + 1, b, [...r, a])   // #2
: [...r, a]                        // #3

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(0,7)))   // [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(3,9)))   // [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(9,3)))   // [9,8,7,6,5,4,3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-3,-7))) // [-3,-4,-5,-6,-7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-7,-3))) // [-7,-6,-5,-4,-3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(2,-2)))  // [2,1,0,-1,-2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(-2,2)))  // [-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

Comment: And tail recursive to boot!

Answer (score 2):

This is largely the same answer as the one from Ori Drori -- the first, functional one, not the barbaric imperative one :-) -- but with a simpler base case, with the spread operator in place of `concat`, and by counting down `end` rather than counting up `start`.  I guess that, at that point, it's really not the same function at all, but it still feels very similar in spirit.

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (start, end) =>
  start > end
    ? []
    : [... rangeOfNumbers (start, end - 1), end]


console .log (rangeOfNumbers (3, 12))
```

The point here is that recursive approaches are often much simpler than imperative ones.  If we know that for any shorter range our function will return what it's supposed to, then our recursive case is often very simple.  So here, if we know that `rangeOfNumbers(3, 11)` will yield `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`, then we can easily solve our current case, by tacking `12` onto the end.  Then with a little thought about base cases, we can easily stitch together our function.

Comment: lol - "not the barbaric imperative one :-)". Yea - I felt dirty when writing it.

Comment: I've taken to talking about avoiding mutation by pointing out that we're not barbarians here.

Comment: btw - which approach would enjoy tail call optimization?

Comment: @OriDori I provided a tail-recursive form in my post :D

Comment: Yeah, I didn't bother, but it's simple enough

Answer (score 1):

This moves the array to inside the function, you just have to declare an empty one when calling it for the first time.

```js
const rangeOfNumbers = (startNum, endNum, array) => {
    if (startNum === endNum) {
        array.splice(0, 0, startNum);
        return array;
    }
    array.splice(0, 0, endNum);
    // console.log(array)
    const newEndNum = endNum - 1;
    endNum = newEndNum;
    return rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum, array);
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(6, 10, []));
```